# Getting SOAP response from object

Tags: php, soap, drupal

*Originally posted on Drupal Answers, but it's more of a PHP/SOAP question.*

I am trying to get a specific cookie from a SOAP login.

For some reason I can't get this to work with Drupal 8.

I am doing the following:

```
$login = new \ilib\membership\LoginUserAndProvideCookies('USERNAME', 'PASSWORD', TRUE);
```

dpm($login_result, "ilib_connect login");

However then $login looks like this:

```
ilib_connect login => stdClass Object
(
    [__CLASS__] => ilib\membership\LoginUserAndProvideCookiesResponse
    [LoginUserAndProvideCookiesResult] => stdClass Object
        (
            [__CLASS__] => ilib\membership\LoginUserAndProvideCookies
            [username] => USERNAME
            [password] => PASSWORD
            [staffUser] => 1
        )

)
```

Whereas in SoapUI, I get the following response XML from the same command:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <soap:Body>
      <LoginUserAndProvideCookiesResponse xmlns="http://ilib.domain/webservices/membership">
         <LoginUserAndProvideCookiesResult>ASP.NET_SessionId=<LONG STRING OF CHARACTERS>|Login=|Login=<LONG STRING OF CHARACTERS></LoginUserAndProvideCookiesResult>
      </LoginUserAndProvideCookiesResponse>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

One of the two  being what I want to get.

Why exactly isn't this being returned?

There's no result method. There is a response method, but when I pass in that object, it just provides me the same information.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that a classmap wasn't set.

For one of the options, you need to have `"classmap" => <map of classes here>`